# Unity build error: "Could not find file...build.asm.js "

Tags: unity, c#, webgl, build-process

I made a WebGL game and the first few times it built well, then I continued working on it a bit and when I build it it gives me an error (and does not generate the build files), error: FileNotFoundException:

> Could not find file "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Infinite
>   Side Scroller\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native\build.asm.js".

Heres the full error message:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Infinite Side Scroller\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native\build.asm.js".
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:305)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:363)
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:167)
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string,System.Text.Encoding)
>   System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:587)
>   System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:582)
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.CodeAnalysisUtils.ReplaceDuplicates (System.String builtCodePath, Int32 interations) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/CodeAnalysisUtils.cs:145)
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:589)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:186)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

What is the problem? And how can I fix it?

Feel free to ask me for more information?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: this seems to be a unity bug

Comment: [Related reading](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/asm-js-and-webgl-for-unity-and-unreal-engine.339431/)

Comment: It looks like you have some file access code in your game.  You cannot call Filestream in WebGL.

Comment: What would be an common use of Filestream? (to give me an idea where I could have used it, since I'm not familiar with it)

Comment: Look for any reference to System.IO.FileStream in your code.

Comment: I don't remember coding it however, I'm not even sure I ever used/ knew it

Comment: If you're using a package that is from the store, that package might be using it instead. You'd have to identify which one.

Comment: I'm not using any packages, is this the only reason for the error?